# "elements in" vs "elements of"

Tags: grammaticality, mathematics

Let *A* be a set, which of the following is grammatically correct

1. an element **in** *A*, elements **in** *A*, a subset **in** *A*, subsets **in** *A*, or
2. an element **of** *A*, elements **of** *A*, a subset **of** *A*, subsets **of** *A*?

I have seen both used in the literature, but I am not sure if they are used correctly. If both are grammatically correct, is there any difference in the meaning?

Answer (score 2):

When the context is about mathematical sets, the term *elements of A* is commonly accepted.

> Two sets A and B are said to be disjoint, if *no element of A* is in B
>   and *no element of B* is in A.

However, for other types of sets *elements in A* is also acceptable.

When you are referring to the number of elements, you say: *the number of elements in A*:

> The number of elements in set A is 6.